# ウィジェットの表示幅が実機とエミュレータとで合わない

Tags: android-studio, ウィジェット

スマホアプリを開発している初心者です。

Andoroid Studio で開発しているのですが、ウィジェットの幅がPCの画面上と実機で合っていません。

実機のスマホ機種はSO-04Hを使用しています。
何故このような現象が起こるのか解らず苦戦しております。
アドバイス頂けると助かります。

**実機上での表示:**

[image]

**エミュレータ上での表示:**

[image]

以下xmlファイルのコード

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/schedule_text01"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/style_01"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint=" 予定内容を入力"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="3"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/back"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/schedule01" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/style_01"
    android:hint="予定保存"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/schedule01" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/style_01"
    android:hint="予定クリア"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/schedule_time01"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/style_02"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint=" 予定日時を入力　例：20200924"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="3"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/back"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/schedule_text01" />
```

Comment: 実機とエミュレータとで画面の解像度 (ディスプレイサイズ) は一致していますか？

Comment: すいません、実機とエミュレータの解像度の合わせ方はどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: エミュレータの仮想デバイスを作成する際、画面の解像度を設定できるはずなので、こちらを実機と同じ寸法にしておくと動作確認の意味でもよいのかなと思いました。 - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds?hl=ja

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
設定を見直してみます。